# Error importing Dynamics NAV web service in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I'm trying, in Visual Studio 2010, to add a Web Reference to a Dynamics NAV webservice that asks me for a username\password (domain user : domain\user.

If I try in the browser, after putting the user/password I get to the WSDL with no problem.

In "Add Web Reference" window in VS2010 I get the following message in the "Web Services found at this URL" box :

> *There was an error downloading 'WS URL?wsdl'. The request failed with the error message:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <s:Body> <s:Fault> <faultcode xmlns:a="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/e**
```

It seems it's missing the rest of the error message.
I've searched in Event Viewer for a similar error but nothing found.

I found in the "Security" section in Event Viewer an "Audit Success" event to the supplied user/password in the Web Service server  as **Target Server** and then 3 similar events but with the user that is logged in the machine i'm using.

It seems it tries to retrieve part of the Web Service information with the supplied user and the rest of the info with the logged in user.
And with the logged in user it doesn't retrieve the info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Visual Studio as Administrator?